# Couldn't enable DataBinging for project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-databinding

When I'm trying to enable Databinding in newly created test project (`dataBinding {enable=true}`), I get the message

```
Could not set unknown property 'enable' for object of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.DataBindingOptions.
```

Also there is no autocompletion for the data binding. (But it is here for `app.dataBinding` - but I can't understand how to use it)

My app.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    dataBinding {
        enable = true
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.testapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
}
```

And project gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext{
        kotlin_version = '1.3.21'
        gradleVersion = '3.1.0'
    }
    ...
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Android Studio 3.3.1, Support library is installed (with Android support repository etc.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to replace

```
dataBinding
{
    enable = true
}
```

with

```
dataBinding
{
    enabled = true
}
```